# Safari bug in FileList?

Tags: javascript, file, safari, filelist

I seem to have run up against a bug in Safari's FileList but I'd like to see if anyone has any ideas on how to workaround the problem.

The HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" onchange="alert(this.files[0].size);" />
```

When selecting one file, the size is accurate.  If two or more files are selected, 0 bytes is reported.

This isn't just a bug in reporting the size of the files, the File objects are empty - when I append a file to a FormData object and post via xhr, there is no data in the upload.

The uploads work fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a windows port bug and it affects any attempt to use multiple files, including a basic form submit:

[file input size issue in safari for multiple file selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231054/file-input-size-issue-in-safari-for-multiple-file-selection)

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/703

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/363