# Cordova iOS 10.3.1 breaks input file for videos

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, ios10, ios10.3

This is similar to this much older issue: [HTML file input with multi selection in UIWebView not working for videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156467/html-file-input-with-multi-selection-in-uiwebview-not-working-for-videos)

This is NOT a duplicate of this: [iOS update to 10.3.1 breaks HTML input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396109/ios-update-to-10-3-1-breaks-html-input-element)

I have tested this on my app that was working, on versions going back 45 days, it seems iOS 10.3.1 changed the file input and now there is the multiple video selection, without the "compressing" stage that occurred after selection and before switching out of the interface. Tested on iphone 6S.

When access the the video file via javascript, there is no size or content (compare to image at the bottom, which works):
[http://i.imgur.com/ms2hSiG.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbYia.png)

Comment: I have exact same issue. Have you managed to get it working yet?

Comment: I did not find one, I had to switch to the mediacapture and camera plugins, combined with the file plugin, which are able to replicate both video recording and video file picking, though not with the same UI as the HTML file input where users can choose either (or more, as they can also pick files from icloud, and other apps).

Comment: I am getting the same issue when selecting a video file through the input. The size of the selected file is 0. However when I select an image file, then it works fine and I can get the image correctly. Interestingly enough it looks like you can capture video through the Input and that will give you the correct video file with size > 0.

Comment: I have exact same issue and I've been more than a week trying to find a solution, his is caused by a bug in IOS 10.3 with UIWebView, which makes all file input to have the multiple attribute set automatically. Fixed by using WKWebView instead. Solution on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411176/apple-file-syste%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bm-permission-to-read%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-from-photo-library/%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B43417649#43417649 In my case I'm using the cordova, so I installed this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine